# alert is not working. After success coding is not working

Tags: jquery

here is my problem.

my code working fine.  when i put the breakpoint in script of mozilla firefox browser and then run the application.

but it is not running when i took the breakpoint. even alert also not diplaying.

here is my code

```
function OpenOrdershipment() 
{
    var  arrayOrderId = '';
    var arrayChannelOrderReference = new Array();
    var Url = '<%: Url.Action("OrderShipment", "Shipments") %>';
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        url: Url,
        data: "strOrderId=" + arrayOrderId + "&ChannelOrderReference=" + arrayChannelOrderReference + "&strOpenShipments=" + 1,
        dataType: "HTML",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data != "0" && data != "") {
                alert(data);
                arrOrderId = data;
                $('#Hiddenid').val(arrOrderId);
                document.forms["shipform"].submit();
            }
            else {
                SucessErrorMessageDisplay('DivSuccessErrorMess', 'lblSuccessError', 'imgStatus', 1, 'There is no open shipments');
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            if (xhr.status == 403) {
                window.location.href = '<%: Url.Action( "SessionExpire", "Home" ) %>';
            }
        }
    });
}

    <% using (Html.BeginForm("OrderShipments", "Shipments", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "shipform" })) // Creates <form>
       {%>
    <input type="hidden" id="Hiddenid" name="orderId" />
    <input type="submit" value="book" style="display: none" />
    <%} %>
```

What is the reason? why it is not working?...

Comment: On which line did you put the breakpoint? Did the alert display with the breakpoint on?

Answer (score 0):

**`if (data != "0" && data != "") {`**

You are treating 0 as a string, so obvioulsy it doesn't get inside the function to execute alert and next statements....

Comment: i got it my self i missed # in href      <a onclick="OpenOrdershipment();" href="#">Process Open Shipment </a> not it is working